# ProGuard fails with "Warning: class [*] unexpectedly contains class [*]", despite reading the FAQ

Tags: scala, proguard

I need to shrink the Scala library down so it can be included in an applet, but I keep getting errors like: `[Being$$anon$1.class] unexpectedly contains class [stayAway.Being$$anon$1]` (I get a similar error for each class in the directory).

I looked at the ProGuard FAQ, and it says that this error means my directory isn't configured properly. As far as I can tell though, it is.

I have 8 class files; all a part of the stayAway package.
It's set up like:

```
- stayAway
    - Being$$anon$1.class
    - Being$.class
    - Being.class
    - MainFrame.class
    - NPC$.class
    - NPC.class
    - Player$.class
    - Player.class
```

Using the following configuration (Generated by the ProGuard GUI):

```
-injars 'C:\Users\Brendon\Desktop\stayAway'
-outjars 'C:\Users\Brendon\Desktop\scalaLibraryShrunk.jar'

-libraryjars 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_40\lib\rt.jar'
-libraryjars 'C:\Users\Brendon\Desktop\scala-library.jar'

-dontobfuscate


# Keep - Applications. Keep all application classes, along with their 'main'
# methods.
-keepclasseswithmembers public class * {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}

# Keep - Applets. Keep all extensions of java.applet.Applet.
-keep public class * extends java.applet.Applet

# Keep - Library. Keep all public and protected classes, fields, and methods.
-keep public class * {
    public protected <fields>;
    public protected <methods>;
}

# Also keep - Enumerations. Keep the special static methods that are required in
# enumeration classes.
-keepclassmembers enum  * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

# Also keep - Database drivers. Keep all implementations of java.sql.Driver.
-keep class * extends java.sql.Driver

# Also keep - Swing UI L&F. Keep all extensions of javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI,
# along with the special 'createUI' method.
-keep class * extends javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI {
    public static javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI createUI(javax.swing.JComponent);
}

# Keep names - Native method names. Keep all native class/method names.
-keepclasseswithmembers,includedescriptorclasses,allowshrinking class * {
    native <methods>;
}

# Remove - System method calls. Remove all invocations of System
# methods without side effects whose return values are not used.
-assumenosideeffects public class java.lang.System {
    public static long currentTimeMillis();
    static java.lang.Class getCallerClass();
    public static int identityHashCode(java.lang.Object);
    public static java.lang.SecurityManager getSecurityManager();
    public static java.util.Properties getProperties();
    public static java.lang.String getProperty(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.String getenv(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.String mapLibraryName(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.String getProperty(java.lang.String,java.lang.String);
}

# Remove - Math method calls. Remove all invocations of Math
# methods without side effects whose return values are not used.
-assumenosideeffects public class java.lang.Math {
    public static double sin(double);
    public static double cos(double);
    public static double tan(double);
    public static double asin(double);
    public static double acos(double);
    public static double atan(double);
    public static double toRadians(double);
    public static double toDegrees(double);
    public static double exp(double);
    public static double log(double);
    public static double log10(double);
    public static double sqrt(double);
    public static double cbrt(double);
    public static double IEEEremainder(double,double);
    public static double ceil(double);
    public static double floor(double);
    public static double rint(double);
    public static double atan2(double,double);
    public static double pow(double,double);
    public static int round(float);
    public static long round(double);
    public static double random();
    public static int abs(int);
    public static long abs(long);
    public static float abs(float);
    public static double abs(double);
    public static int max(int,int);
    public static long max(long,long);
    public static float max(float,float);
    public static double max(double,double);
    public static int min(int,int);
    public static long min(long,long);
    public static float min(float,float);
    public static double min(double,double);
    public static double ulp(double);
    public static float ulp(float);
    public static double signum(double);
    public static float signum(float);
    public static double sinh(double);
    public static double cosh(double);
    public static double tanh(double);
    public static double hypot(double,double);
    public static double expm1(double);
    public static double log1p(double);
}

# Remove - Number method calls. Remove all invocations of Number
# methods without side effects whose return values are not used.
-assumenosideeffects public class java.lang.* extends java.lang.Number {
    public static java.lang.String toString(byte);
    public static java.lang.Byte valueOf(byte);
    public static byte parseByte(java.lang.String);
    public static byte parseByte(java.lang.String,int);
    public static java.lang.Byte valueOf(java.lang.String,int);
    public static java.lang.Byte valueOf(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.Byte decode(java.lang.String);
    public int compareTo(java.lang.Byte);
    public static java.lang.String toString(short);
    public static short parseShort(java.lang.String);
    public static short parseShort(java.lang.String,int);
    public static java.lang.Short valueOf(java.lang.String,int);
    public static java.lang.Short valueOf(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.Short valueOf(short);
    public static java.lang.Short decode(java.lang.String);
    public static short reverseBytes(short);
    public int compareTo(java.lang.Short);
    public static java.lang.String toString(int,int);
    public static java.lang.String toHexString(int);
    public static java.lang.String toOctalString(int);
    public static java.lang.String toBinaryString(int);
    public static java.lang.String toString(int);
    public static int parseInt(java.lang.String,int);
    public static int parseInt(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.Integer valueOf(java.lang.String,int);
    public static java.lang.Integer valueOf(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.Integer valueOf(int);
    public static java.lang.Integer getInteger(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.Integer getInteger(java.lang.String,int);
    public static java.lang.Integer getInteger(java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer);
    public static java.lang.Integer decode(java.lang.String);
    public static int highestOneBit(int);
    public static int lowestOneBit(int);
    public static int numberOfLeadingZeros(int);
    public static int numberOfTrailingZeros(int);
    public static int bitCount(int);
    public static int rotateLeft(int,int);
    public static int rotateRight(int,int);
    public static int reverse(int);
    public static int signum(int);
    public static int reverseBytes(int);
    public int compareTo(java.lang.Integer);
    public static java.lang.String toString(long,int);
    public static java.lang.String toHexString(long);
    public static java.lang.String toOctalString(long);
    public static java.lang.String toBinaryString(long);
    public static java.lang.String toString(long);
    public static long parseLong(java.lang.String,int);
    public static long parseLong(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.Long valueOf(java.lang.String,int);
    public static java.lang.Long valueOf(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.Long valueOf(long);
    public static java.lang.Long decode(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.Long getLong(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.Long getLong(java.lang.String,long);
    public static java.lang.Long getLong(java.lang.String,java.lang.Long);
    public static long highestOneBit(long);
    public static long lowestOneBit(long);
    public static int numberOfLeadingZeros(long);
    public static int numberOfTrailingZeros(long);
    public static int bitCount(long);
    public static long rotateLeft(long,int);
    public static long rotateRight(long,int);
    public static long reverse(long);
    public static int signum(long);
    public static long reverseBytes(long);
    public int compareTo(java.lang.Long);
    public static java.lang.String toString(float);
    public static java.lang.String toHexString(float);
    public static java.lang.Float valueOf(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.Float valueOf(float);
    public static float parseFloat(java.lang.String);
    public static boolean isNaN(float);
    public static boolean isInfinite(float);
    public static int floatToIntBits(float);
    public static int floatToRawIntBits(float);
    public static float intBitsToFloat(int);
    public static int compare(float,float);
    public boolean isNaN();
    public boolean isInfinite();
    public int compareTo(java.lang.Float);
    public static java.lang.String toString(double);
    public static java.lang.String toHexString(double);
    public static java.lang.Double valueOf(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.Double valueOf(double);
    public static double parseDouble(java.lang.String);
    public static boolean isNaN(double);
    public static boolean isInfinite(double);
    public static long doubleToLongBits(double);
    public static long doubleToRawLongBits(double);
    public static double longBitsToDouble(long);
    public static int compare(double,double);
    public boolean isNaN();
    public boolean isInfinite();
    public int compareTo(java.lang.Double);
    public byte byteValue();
    public short shortValue();
    public int intValue();
    public long longValue();
    public float floatValue();
    public double doubleValue();
    public int compareTo(java.lang.Object);
    public boolean equals(java.lang.Object);
    public int hashCode();
    public java.lang.String toString();
}

# Remove - String method calls. Remove all invocations of String
# methods without side effects whose return values are not used.
-assumenosideeffects public class java.lang.String {
    public static java.lang.String copyValueOf(char[]);
    public static java.lang.String copyValueOf(char[],int,int);
    public static java.lang.String valueOf(boolean);
    public static java.lang.String valueOf(char);
    public static java.lang.String valueOf(char[]);
    public static java.lang.String valueOf(char[],int,int);
    public static java.lang.String valueOf(double);
    public static java.lang.String valueOf(float);
    public static java.lang.String valueOf(int);
    public static java.lang.String valueOf(java.lang.Object);
    public static java.lang.String valueOf(long);
    public boolean contentEquals(java.lang.StringBuffer);
    public boolean endsWith(java.lang.String);
    public boolean equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String);
    public boolean equals(java.lang.Object);
    public boolean matches(java.lang.String);
    public boolean regionMatches(boolean,int,java.lang.String,int,int);
    public boolean regionMatches(int,java.lang.String,int,int);
    public boolean startsWith(java.lang.String);
    public boolean startsWith(java.lang.String,int);
    public byte[] getBytes();
    public byte[] getBytes(java.lang.String);
    public char charAt(int);
    public char[] toCharArray();
    public int compareToIgnoreCase(java.lang.String);
    public int compareTo(java.lang.Object);
    public int compareTo(java.lang.String);
    public int hashCode();
    public int indexOf(int);
    public int indexOf(int,int);
    public int indexOf(java.lang.String);
    public int indexOf(java.lang.String,int);
    public int lastIndexOf(int);
    public int lastIndexOf(int,int);
    public int lastIndexOf(java.lang.String);
    public int lastIndexOf(java.lang.String,int);
    public int length();
    public java.lang.CharSequence subSequence(int,int);
    public java.lang.String concat(java.lang.String);
    public java.lang.String replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String);
    public java.lang.String replace(char,char);
    public java.lang.String replaceFirst(java.lang.String,java.lang.String);
    public java.lang.String[] split(java.lang.String);
    public java.lang.String[] split(java.lang.String,int);
    public java.lang.String substring(int);
    public java.lang.String substring(int,int);
    public java.lang.String toLowerCase();
    public java.lang.String toLowerCase(java.util.Locale);
    public java.lang.String toString();
    public java.lang.String toUpperCase();
    public java.lang.String toUpperCase(java.util.Locale);
    public java.lang.String trim();
}

# Remove - StringBuffer method calls. Remove all invocations of StringBuffer
# methods without side effects whose return values are not used.
-assumenosideeffects public class java.lang.StringBuffer {
    public java.lang.String toString();
    public char charAt(int);
    public int capacity();
    public int codePointAt(int);
    public int codePointBefore(int);
    public int indexOf(java.lang.String,int);
    public int lastIndexOf(java.lang.String);
    public int lastIndexOf(java.lang.String,int);
    public int length();
    public java.lang.String substring(int);
    public java.lang.String substring(int,int);
}

# Remove - StringBuilder method calls. Remove all invocations of StringBuilder
# methods without side effects whose return values are not used.
-assumenosideeffects public class java.lang.StringBuilder {
    public java.lang.String toString();
    public char charAt(int);
    public int capacity();
    public int codePointAt(int);
    public int codePointBefore(int);
    public int indexOf(java.lang.String,int);
    public int lastIndexOf(java.lang.String);
    public int lastIndexOf(java.lang.String,int);
    public int length();
    public java.lang.String substring(int);
    public java.lang.String substring(int,int);
}
```

And here's the exact error message:

```
ProGuard, version 5.2
Reading program directory [C:\Users\Brendon\Desktop\stayAway]
Warning: class [Being$$anon$1.class] unexpectedly contains class [stayAway.Being$$anon$1]
Warning: class [Being$.class] unexpectedly contains class [stayAway.Being$]
Warning: class [Being.class] unexpectedly contains class [stayAway.Being]
Warning: class [MainFrame.class] unexpectedly contains class [stayAway.MainFrame]
Warning: class [NPC$.class] unexpectedly contains class [stayAway.NPC$]
Warning: class [NPC.class] unexpectedly contains class [stayAway.NPC]
Warning: class [Player$.class] unexpectedly contains class [stayAway.Player$]
Warning: class [Player.class] unexpectedly contains class [stayAway.Player]
Reading library jar [C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_40\lib\rt.jar]
Reading library jar [C:\Users\Brendon\Desktop\scala-library.jar]
Warning: there were 8 classes in incorrectly named files.
         You should make sure all file names correspond to their class names.
         The directory hierarchies must correspond to the package hierarchies.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unexpectedclass)
         If you don't mind the mentioned classes not being written out,
         you could try your luck using the '-ignorewarnings' option.
Please correct the above warnings first.
```

This is my first time using ProGuard, so I may be overlooking something.
Any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your class files need to be in a directory called "stayAway" to match the package name, but I think this directory must be relative to the input directory.
In other words, I think your input directory

C:\Users\Brendon\Desktop\stayAway

contains the class files?  But if this is your input directory, you need the class files to be in

C:\Users\Brendon\Desktop\stayAway\stayAway

Similarly, you could set your input directory to

C:\Users\Brendon\Desktop\input

and put the class files in

C:\Users\Brendon\Desktop\input\stayAway

Comment: So I just need to nest it in another directory? I'll try it (I REALLY hope you're right or I'll have to translate the entire applet into Java :/)

Comment: You were right; adding the extra folder fixed it. ProGuard is messing with the library now though, because it's not allowing the applet to load (but thats beyond the scope of this question). Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.  You would have had the same problem in Java, I think.  ProGuard expected your folder structure to mirror the package structure, using the input directory as the root.  In the original example, all of your class files were in the "root" package directory (which happened to be named "C:\Users\Brendon\Desktop\stayAway" in the file system).